# Object change notification in google app engine will affect the billing amount?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am using automatic file loader for ETL on google cloud console for loading data in to google bigquery.
billing amount is increasing unexpectedly. i am not getting the reason why this is happening. this might be because of bucket watching.

Comment: Need more details and an actual question.  What costs are increasing, for example?

Comment: I am using the object change notification because of this my compute engine is running for 24 hours

Comment: I am running the cron for processing the script which generate the json file for loading it to bigquery. so I want the compute engine to start when my cron runs and stop after processing is done is it possible ?

Comment: This may be a case where contacting the [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) team may be the best option, as it sounds like you have an intermingled set of issues to work through.